# In React, why can't I pass a function reference to onClick?

Tags: reactjs, anonymous-function

I usually split my React applications by having a JSX component with only UI on one side, and a singleton class for business logic on the other side.

The UI component code would look like this:

```
function Component () {
    const [state, setState] = useState(ComponentLogic.defaultState)

    // this line stores an instance of the logic class as a singleton
    // thanks to the useState statement
    const [logic] = useState(new ComponentLogic(setState))

    return <p onClick={ logic.setTheState }></p>
}
```

And the logic class:

```
class ComponentLogic {
    static defaultState = {
        property: 'value'
    }

    constructor(private setState) { }

    setTheState() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            property: 'The state has been set'
        })
    }
}
```

I find this way of organising my code very efficient and scalable. But the thing is, I generally have this error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')**

So the way I have been dealing with this up to this day is by passing an anonymous function to the UI component:

```
<p onClick={ () => logic.setTheState() }></p>
```

## My question

Why do I need to wrap it in an anonymous function, and not simply reference the class function ?

Comment: You're chasing the wrong problem. It has nothing to do with passing a function reference to `onClick`, and has everything to do with `ComponentLogic` *not* being a component with a `this.setState` property.

Comment: `ComponentLogic` is a regular class, and I don't see any value it provides. I think you're making your code significantly more complicated than it needs to be by using it. Just use `useState` as intented

Comment: @BrianThompson `setState` is a private field (see that `private setState` in the ctor)

Comment: @FuméeNoire when executing `setTheState` for `onClick` you have `this` set to the HTML element, not the class instance. You could define that function as property or call `bind()` to bind `this` to the instance (probably in your ctor).

Comment: Fair enough, I missed that line. So the problem is instead related to `this` not referring to the class instance. But the point still stands that this pattern is not a good idea and removing it will solve their problems

Comment: But what' you're doing is a bit _strange_ in general. This is not how you're expected to use hooks (changes to the state won't trigger rerenderings, for example)

Comment: @BrianThompson absolutely, the idea is sensible but this specific implementation is unusual enough to become confusing/error prone/surprising

Comment: @BrianThompson @AdrianoRepetti thanks guys. Actually, I have been using this approach professionally on numerous projects and for components with complex logic and UI, this has been a relief of a design pattern - though I understand this can be confusing. And, setting the state from the class does trigger a rerender on the component side ! This allows me to decouple logic from UI.

Anyway, the answer was actually quite simple and I thank you for that, I think I will go with binding `this` in my class' constructor and everything will be fine.

Comment: @FuméeNoire if you want to decouple logic from your UI, use custom hooks. This is the react way. Your code is not following a design pattern, it's just nonsense from someone who doesn't know how to use react (and even basic HTML apparently).

Comment: @BaptisteF. détends-toi  **no need to hate**, we are all here to learn. You obviously have not worked in a professional React environment where you have complex logic along with robust testing. Custom hooks are meant to extract logic as a reusable code base for multiple components - in my case, the logic that gets extracted only belongs to its component, and would have polluted the UI file with unrelated JSX code. When you work on larger projects that require team work and code standards, our particular way of handling this problem was very accommodating and easy to implement / maintain.

Comment: @FuméeNoire Custom hooks make it possible to reuse logic across multiple components, but it's not a requirement. Nothing prevents you to only use it once. 

So this is what you need to do: extract your logic into a custom hook, put it in the same folder that your component file. And voilà ! Your goal is achieved. It's clean, it's readable, it's easy to maintain / test and even a new react developer joining your team will be able to understand the code (which is definitely not the case with your class baloney).

Peace.

Comment: @FuméeNoire I see where you're going. This is more for CR than SO but...I appreciate that having pure logic classes makes them easier to test than hooks but a slightly more idiomatic way to do it would be to have a custom hook to aggregate those two `useState()`. Even better: the 2nd one doesn't need to have `useState()`: possibly `useMemo()` if not simply `useRef()`. Callers would then have something like `const [state, logic] = useLogic<ComponentLogic>();` (if using TS).

Comment: With that done then you;re basically implementing a state manager. I am NOT a big fan of Redux but I like Recoil and it _could_ fit your usage pattern/preference pretty well. There are plenty of options out there and they _could_ help you to decouple logic from UI (and make it easier to test in isolation). The difference is that they usually perform MUCH better than our hand-made solutions when components are numerous or complex. In your next 10% you could give them a try to see if they fit your way of thinking.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti you were right, I changed my mind and went for a custom hook instead of Javascript classes, and this works identically, if not better because of the use of native React elements. Thanks for your feedback :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was related to the object `this`. To quote Adriano Repetti's answer:

> when executing setTheState for onClick you have this set to the HTML element, not the class instance. You could define that function as property or call bind() to bind this to the instance (probably in your ctor)

I will bind `this` inside the constructor of the logic class in the future, thanks guys